# Determine the set $A$ of values of $x$ for which the series converges pointwise(3)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Determine the set $A$ of values of $x$ for which the series converges pointwise, and whether convergence is uniform on $A$. If not, determine a set $B⊂A$ such that the series converges uniformly on $B.$

$$∑_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{2n - 1}\biggl(\frac{x + 2}{x -1}\biggr)^n $$

**My answer is:**

1- the values of $x$ for which the series converges pointwise are $A=(-\infty ,-1/2).$, I got this value after setting $\bigl|\frac{x + 2}{x-1}\bigr| < 1$.

2- Since the series converges pointwisely to  $\bigl|\frac{x + 2}{x-1}\bigr|$ when $x < -1/2,$, I that I can use the supremum property to check if the series converges uniformly on $A$, also I know that this supremum must go to $0$ for the series to converge uniformly on $A$, $\sup_{x \in A} \bigl|\frac{1}{2n - 1}(\frac{x + 2}{x -1})^n - \bigl|\frac{x + 2}{x-1}\bigr|\bigr|$, but I do not know how to deal with the quantity inside the absolute value to show either the convergence or not to 0, could anyone help me in doing this  please? and if not what is the set $B$ on which the  series can converge uniformly?

Comment: I am asking here about uniform convergence ...... not pointwise ..... and I have some comments on the question their that you did not answer ..... could you please look at them ? (by the way you answered some of them here but you said in the second case there that it is divergent .... also I asked you about the third case there and you did not answer me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series converges uniformly on $\{x:|\frac {x+2} {x-1}| \leq 1-\epsilon\}$ for any $\epsilon >0$ but it does not converge uniformly on $\{x:|\frac {x+2} {x-1}| < 1\}$. Hints: use properties of the much simpler series $\sum \frac 1 {2n-1} y^{n}$ and then put $y=\frac {x+2} {x-1}$.

Detailed proof of the fact that $\sum \frac 1 {2n-1} y^{n}$ does not converge uniformly for $|y|<1$: if it does converge uniformly then we can choose $n_0$ such that $ \sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{N_2} |\frac 1 {2n-1} y^{n}|<1$ whenever $N_2>N_1>n_0$. If $N_2$ is large enough we have $(1-\frac 1 {N_2})^{N_2} >\frac 1 {2e}$. Now take $y=1-\frac 1 {N_2}$ to get a contradiction if $N_2$ is so large that  $\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{N_2} |\frac 1 {2n-1} |>2e$.

Comment: why could you please add details?

Comment: I was asking above about the quantity in the absolute value how can I deal with?

Comment: You have to solve the inequality $|\frac {x+2} {x-1}| \leq 1$ by considering four possibilities based on the signs of $x+2$ and $x-1$.

Comment: could you please look at my comments in the other link?

Comment: No I am not asking about this absolute value ................. I am asking about the one I mentioned above in the question

Comment: how can I do this? what are the details for doing this?

Comment: @hopefully I have given some details now.

Comment: Thank you so much Kavi

Comment: I can not see the relation between e and  the given sequence .... why are you comparing it to e?